# How to get macOS to present a dropped .stl file as public.standard-tesselated-geometry-format?

Tags: swift, macos, drag-and-drop, swiftui

I'm trying to add some drag-and-drop support to my SwiftUI macOS app to allow the user to drop `.stl` files onto the window. I’ve got the drop working, but I only seem to be able to validate against `public.file-url`, rather than the specific `public.standard-tesselated-geometry-format` (provided by `ModelIO` as `kUTTypeStereolithography`).

In my code, I do something like this:

```swift
    func
    validateDrop(info inInfo: DropInfo)
        -> Bool
    {
        debugLog("STL: \(kUTTypeStereolithography)")
        let has = inInfo.hasItemsConforming(to: [kUTTypeFileURL as String, kUTTypeData as String])
        return has
    }

    func
    performDrop(info inInfo: DropInfo)
        -> Bool
    {
        inInfo.itemProviders(for: [kUTTypeFileURL as String, kUTTypeData as String, kUTTypeStereolithography]).forEach
        { inItem in
            debugLog("UTIs: \(inItem.registeredTypeIdentifiers)")
            inItem.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeFileURL as String, options: nil)
            { (inURLData, inError) in
                if let error = inError
                {
                    debugLog("Error: \(error)")
                    return
                }

                if let urlData = inURLData as? Data,
                    let url = URL(dataRepresentation: urlData, relativeTo: nil)
                {
                    debugLog("Dropped '\(url.path)'")
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

This works well enough if I look for `kUTTypeFileURL`, but not if I look for `kUTTypeStereolithography` when I drop a `.stl` file onto the view.

I tried declaring it as an imported type but a) that didn’t seem to work and b) shouldn’t be necessary, since the existence of a symbolic constant implies macOS know about the type. I also don’t really know what it conforms to, although I tried both `public.data` and `public.file-url`.

I’d really like to be able to validate the type so that the user isn’t mislead by the drop UI. Currently, it indicates that my view will accept the drop if it’s not an `.stl` file, which I don’t want it to do.

Comment: If you drag from Finder, then yes, Finder does note know anything about kUTTypeStereolithography (which is specific format), for Finder it is just file with URL, but some specific software can put into pasteboard exactly that type, so your app should support both.

Comment: Really, the Finder doesn't match the file extension to a database of known (or declared by my app) UTIs? Okay, how can I validate the file type then before the drop UI indicates it can be dropped? I don't seem to be able to get at the file URL in `DropDelegate.validateDrop(info:)`.

Comment: macOS and iOS differ in how file drops are handled.  For iOS, the NSItemProvider for .onDrop contains a reference to the file, and the UTI is that of the actual file, so a custom UTI can be validated. For macOS, the NSItemProvider contains a reference to the URL for the file, and the UTI of the provider is kUTTypeFileURL, not the UTI of the file itself. I can find no synchronous method to extract the URL or file UTI, or to examine the file metadata/data from the NSItemProvider. Synchronous validation of the actual file does not seem to be possible with macOS, unless I am missing something.